# No need to show the pop-up window after user close it

Tags: php, jquery, magento-1.7

I am new to magento development, in home page we are showing promotional pop-up window to the customer. Now my requirement is, no need to show the pop up again if an user does close the pop up and reload. Now it's opening if an user does close  the pop up and refresh the page.

I don't know which code part should i post here for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie the first time it loads. Only show the popup if the cookie is not set.

Comment: thank u. yeah i am thinking the same way. But in magento case, where i need to do this stuff? in .phtml file?